# Google Maps API v3: SVG graphics clip / disappear when zooming

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, safari

Test link: http://kwestievan.nl/reizen

What I'm doing here: implemented my own OverlayView to draw curved lines from marker to marker with arrowheads at the end of each line with SVG. I add a div element to the map that is of a certain width and height to contain the line and arrowhead. I then put inline SVG code in that div to let the browser draw the line and arrow.

If viewed in Safari or Chrome some very annoying and unexpected behavior occurs. In Safari the whole SVG graphic disappears beyond a certain zoom level, and in Chrome the arrowheads at the end of the line disappear and re-appear at random zoom levels so it seems. In Firefox and Opera this behavior is not happening and the arrowheads are visible at any zoom level.

Don't mind the red boxes and/or the displacement of some arrows. That's work in progress.

What is going on here? Is SVG not fully compatible with Google Maps or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you seen `google.maps.Polyline` and `google.maps.Polygon`? If you encode the path, its away more eficient and consistent than SVG, see `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath`

Comment: @PauloScardine believe me I've tried a lot of things to get nice, curved lines with arrowheads from marker to marker. So far I have the most success with SVG graphics like this. The problem with the built in Polyline and Polygon functions is that they do not offer a built in curved line option. There are numerous extensions for this but they draw on the map, not on the screen. Consequence: over large distances the lines have a deviation due to geodesic correction. So I need to draw entirely 'on the screen', with pixels. To do this I decided to use SVG.

Answer (score 1):

The marker with the infoWindow Shadow? 
Obviously your marker shadow is set to the same values as your `infoWindow`. Duplicate variable maybe? Change the name of your marker shadow 'path'. You may have inadvertently used the same identifier for the marker path name as the `infoWindow` shadow path.

I agree with Star.
Started creating complex SVG paths for `polyLine` icons and they half disappear when placed in certain positions and zoom levels (i.e., when they straddle 2 map tiles). It's blamed on Geodesic correction.

In Firefox your SVG outer line will randomly float around the screen in a larger scale. Something to do with a closure issue. Fixable though.

I dont see why the `polyLine` and its icons can't sit above the map layer and therefore avoid its idiosyncrasies.

Basically I have wasted a lot of time and very disappointed with the results of placing SVGs on a `polyLine`. I did want to sell my bus scheduling and mapping script to transit companies.  But graphically its just not up to a standard I would feel comfortable with. I.e, buses half disappearing and reappearing on the next tile.

I am going to use markers now for my bus icons as they appear to sit on a layer above the map and therefore don't have geodesic attachments.

By the way. You **can** create arcs using polyLine and polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried but failed to embed a Map in SVG. I too am getting very different behaviour between browsers. Looking closely, the Map itself is very complex SVG. There are certainly major differences in the way browsers handle SVG. I have put that bit of development on the back burner, waiting for the browsers to get their act together.
I know this isn't an answer, but just sharing experience.

Comment: The only difference is that I'm not trying to embed a map into SVG, but rather the other way around. I want to draw a SVG graphic on top of the map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making progress. If you look at the test link right now you'll see that in Chrome the arrows stay where they need to be pretty consistent whatever zoom level you are at. Safari still looses the entire SVG graphic past a certain zoom level. Even normal Google InfoWindow instances have this problem, as you can see at the test website with the last marker (zoom out a little to see it).

Judging on this I'm thinking there is actually a bug in Google Maps right now. Can someone else confirm that the InfoWindow itself (not the shadow) disappears after a certain zoom level (somewhere after the middle level)? Like so:

[image: Safari looses InfoWindow past zoom level]

Comment: I use Google Maps heavily and I've never experienced InfoWindows disappearing, ever